# Why won't my contact form send?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have used this contact form before, I just changed out the information. For some reason now though it won't send. I gone over the html and php but I can't see the error. The only difference is that now I'm using godaddy, but other than that I'm not seeing what the error is. HELP!

HTML:

```
<div id="MainForm">
    <form method="post" action="ContactForm-Handler.php" name="Contact Form" target="_parent" id="ContactForm" title="Contact Form">
      <h1>Contact Form</h1>
      <p>Please fill out information below.</p>
      <p>
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" /><br /><br />
        <label for="Email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /><br /><br />
        <label for="QuestionType">Regarding: </label>
        <select name="QuestionType" id="QuestionType">
          <option value="Products">Products</option>
          <option value="Pricing">Pricing</option>
          <option value="Terms">Terms</option>
          <option value="Other Information">Other</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <label for="MessageBox">Message: </label>
        <Br /><br />
        <textarea name="MessageBox" cols="50" rows="10">Enter Question/Message Here</textarea>
      </p>
      <p><input name="Send" type="submit" id="Send" onmouseup="ThankYou.html" value="Submit" />
      </p>
  </form>
  </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['Name']; 
$email = $_POST['Email']; 
$message = $_POST['MessageBox']; 
$question = $_POST['QuestionType'];
if(!empty($_POST['Products'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Products'] as $products) {
            echo $check; 
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['Pricing'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Pricing'] as $pricing) {
            echo $check; 
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['Terms'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Terms'] as $terms) {
            echo $check; 
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['Other Information'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Other Information'] as $other) {
            echo $check; 
    }
}
if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact Form Submission";
    $email_body = "$name needs some information regarding $question \n \n".
    "$message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: ThankYou.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>qp Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The form won't submit or the email won't send?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252471/php-mail-not-working-godaddy-hosted

Comment: P.S. what do you expect `onmouseup="ThankYou.html"` to do?  onmouseup is supposed to be a function not a page.

Comment: you have select box name "QuestionType" and in the posted form looping for products, pricing etc. That is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['Products'])) {
  foreach($_POST['Products'] as $products) {
          echo $check; 
  }
 }
if(!empty($_POST['Pricing'])) {
  foreach($_POST['Pricing'] as $pricing) {
        echo $check; 
  }
 }
if(!empty($_POST['Terms'])) {
  foreach($_POST['Terms'] as $terms) {
         echo $check; 
  }
 }
if(!empty($_POST['Other Information'])) {
  foreach($_POST['Other Information'] as $other) {
         echo $check; 
   }
}
```

Remove this part of your code because here you're checking with the value of the `<option>` tag.
You should use `name` of your `<select>` box instead.

like this :

```
  //we use name attributes. not value attributes. otherwise $_POST will have Undefined Index error.    
if(!empty($_POST['QuestionType'])){
   foreach($_POST['QuestionType'] as $QuestionType){
        echo $check;
    }
 }
```

And yeah, use `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` at the top of your php page to enable php to show you errors.

Comment: make sure you have defined $check variable some where earlier in the php page. and have a function not a page at  `onMouseUp` it needs to be a function. But that's not the main reason behind the `php` script not running.

Comment: Also, use `PhpMailer` to send emails. It's highly preferred these days.